# html with php: about the method

Tags: php, html

in the html file:

```
<body>
<form action="http://localhost:63342/PHP/06html.php" method="get">
    username:<input type="text" name="name">
    password:<input type="password" name="password">
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">

</form>
</body>
```

in the php file:

```
echo "username:".$_GET["name"]."<br>password:".$_GET["password"];
```

it worked, it shows what I want.

but if I change the method into "post", I also change the php file: $_POST, then it doesn't work.
it shows like this:

```
Notice: Undefined index: name in ***.php on line 10
```

I tried to change it like this:

```
// Before using $_POST['value']
if (isset($_POST['name']))
{
    // Instructions if $_POST['value'] exist
    echo "username:".$_POST["name"];
}
```

but it doesn't work, too

can you guys tell me why and how to fix it?
thanks so much.

Comment: `<form action="http://localhost:63342/PHP/06html.php" method="post">` using this?

Comment: yes...is that right? I learned from some lecture and when I use method get, it worked ... but failed with post....

Comment: ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')

Comment: its working fine on my side, using `method="POST"`

Comment: _Notice: Undefined in line 10_ can you show more code ?

Comment: I only wrote one line code... it says line 10 coz other lines are some information like date or name etc...

Answer (score 0):

This is basic things. please go through w3schools, tutorialpoint website.

use isset function like

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo "username:".$_POST["name"]."<br>password:".$_POST["password"]; 
    }
```

html code: change submit button.

```
 <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this time it shows nothing... it's a blank page

Comment: change action="http://localhost:63342/PHP/06html.php" to action="#". That means you have posted same page. then you will show that username and password echo message.